# Extra AVERAGE row when exporting SSRS report to Excel

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am running SSRS 2008.

When I view my report in SSRS it looks 100%. But when I export the report to excel it adds another row with average values in. Please see below in YELLOW.....

[image]

Why is this and how can I prevent this?

I am using groupings on the report as you can see.

Comment: The extra line might appear from any null values you have within the Space group. Maybe try putting a filter on the group to filter out null values or values you don't want to appear within the group.

Comment: Nope, that 96% is the average of all of the above totals for the date.....it is grouped by date....the report. Nothing to do with null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for this, excel push that row down from the top of the drill down. In SSRS you do not see it but the way Excel works it will always add that row in.

In order to remove that incorrect value of 96% I added in another row group for that column and that remove that value.